# Storing and retrieving multiple values from a foreign table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table "Books", with a column "genres" where I want to reference to another table that contains list of genres.
The problem is that want to store more then one genres in column. 
E.g,

```
ID  | Author          | Title       | Genres
 2  | David Baldacci  |Stone Cold   | 1,4        (action thriller )
```

table "Books Genres"  with 2 columns Id and Genre.

> 1 Action
>   2 Drama
>    3 Comedy
>    4 Thriller
>    5 Horror

Can something like this be done? or it's not practical and I should store genres as simple string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can* be done, but shouldn't.

It is *bad* database design - your database should be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

I suggest an [many-to-many table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) - with `genreId` and `bookId` columns (being foreign keys each, and together forming a composite primary key). This will work as the link you need (a book can have many genres, each genre can write many books).

---

Giving your book as an example with the `Book Genres` table, this would look like:

```
bookId    genreId
2         1
2         4
```

Comment: but how can I "break" the genres?

Comment: @jullin - I think I have explained. I will add an example.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this problem is with what is called a linking table.

A linking table would look like this:

```
 ID (optional) | BookID| GenreID
 1               2       1
 2               2       4
```

Then each book could have multiple rows (or one) in this table.

(The optional ID would be useful if you care about row-level auditing of your tables, or transaction auditing -- you could use it to uniquely id this row -- for your problem it is not needed).

Comment: lol, first with an answer you did not understand and then copied our clearer examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need a third table, perhaps called BookGenre which acts as a "resolver" for the many-many relationship. BookGenre would have two columns, BookID and GenreID. A row would be added to BookGenre for each book for each genre.

There would be two rows in BookGenre for the example data you provided:

```
BookID  GenreID
2       1
2       4
```